# SQL Server how to show detailed information of a delete statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-delete

I wanted to perform a simple delete statement like this:

```
DELETE
FROM table
WHERE table.value = 123
```

and I am expecting the delete 512 rows from the table since those 512 rows have value `123`.

However, there are 5 lines of "xxx rows affected" displayed after running the delete statement.

- The last two lines are identical, "512 lines affected", which is expected.
- The first "512 rows affected" was the actual deletion.
- The second "512 rows affected" was a trigger(the only delete trigger) inserting 512 rows into table_AUDIT.

What about the first 3 lines of "xxx rows affected"?

I don't know which tables are affected so I don't know how to use OUTPUT(googled) to figure out which rows/tables are affected.

My question is: how to display detailed information of the rows deleted? Insert of meaningless "123 rows effected", I like to see which rows from which tables are deleted.

Comment: Welcome to the MSSQL world.  All those "affected" files are the ones _touched_ by any trigger/stored procedure executed. If you have no more than 1 trigger in the table, check for any triggers associated to the table_AUDIT.

Comment: Thanks. There are no triggers associated to table_AUDIT table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do is get a query plan which shall include the triggers. Which rows is something left to your intelligence - query plans generally do not provide this information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.However, I've looked up query plan and do not understand how the query optimization trick is related to my question. Please be more explicit. Thanks.

Comment: it is not. it is still the  best you CAN do. Simple like that - more information is not available, regardless what you wish.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've tried query plan and it does show useful information regarding a query. However, as you mentioned earlier, it's an estimation.

Comment: Actually no, it is anything BUT an estimate IF you get the real executed query plan. It is ONLY an estimation when you get the - attention - ESTIMATED query plan. Maybe reading the documentation is now in order?